# Test PassthroughSubject is subscribed to

Tags: swift

I want to test that some of my PassthroughSubjects are subscribed to on init of my class

my class init is simple:

```
  private let viewType = PassthroughSubject<ViewType, Never>()

  init() {
    setupObservers()
  }

  func setupObservers() {
    viewType
      .sink(
        receiveValue: { [weak self] viewType in
          guard let self = self else {
            return
          }
          self.currentViewType = viewType
          self.titleText.send(viewType.title)
          self.hideXButton.send(viewType.shouldHideXButton)
          self.reloadTableView.send()
        })
      .store(in: &publishers)
   }
```

How can I test that viewType has been subscribed to?

Comment: Since your PassthroughSubject is purely an implementation detail, it makes more sense to test the behaviour of your class. The thing obviously receives a value of type `ViewType` somehow and then it performs mutations on internal variables. You should assert if a certain view type value causes the expected effect.

Answer (score -2):

Add a "print" operator into the middle of your sequence:

```
func setupObservers() {
  viewType
    .print() /* <<< -- Print debugging information*/
    .sink(
      receiveValue: { [weak self] viewType in
    /* Your other code here */
```

It will print debugging information about the values going through the sequence including when a subscriber subscribes to it.

Obviously you should only use this at development time.

In terms of an `XCTest` you ask how to test if your publisher was subscribed to.  The `.sink` operator is inline in your code and would do the subscription so it's not clear what you are trying to verify with an `XCTest`.  You could capture the cancellation return in a variable, store it in your `publishers` set and validate that the cancellation is in the set as a means of ensuring your code was called.  But since your subscription is intrinsic to the code it should always be completed so long as the code runs.

Comment: i was hoping to add an actual test via XCTest

Comment: Please see the revised answer.